# Select x and y on image in particular areas and create a border on it

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am having an issue based on selecting the image.
I have an array of objects which comes from BE and there each Obj hat it own coordinates which depends on the X and Y of the image.
Image has some draws there and includes some numbers.
So the property itemNumber on Obj it is the same number what in img will be shown.
For example if itemNumber is 1 and then the coordinates are that the number 1 will be bordered on image.

I have achieved something till now but I cannot select the right X and Y everytime it is going somewhere else the border.

I created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-ptavcm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In the stackblitz you can find 2 img's.
On the second you will how it should be.
I tried many things but unsuccessful

Here is my Obj json.

```
[
 {
        "itemNumber": "1",
        "partNumber": "4400535240",
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "itemCounter": 0,
                "xposition": 970,
                "yposition": 375
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemNumber": "2",
        "partNumber": "4400541680",
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "itemCounter": 0,
                "xposition": 1282,
                "yposition": 522
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemNumber": "4",
        "partNumber": "4400541390",
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "itemCounter": 0,
                "xposition": 445,
                "yposition": 307
            }
        ]
    },
 ]`
```

Here is my TS Code.

```
showCorner(event: ResponseList) {
console.log(event.coordinates)

const xClientHeight = document.getElementById('imgPath')?.clientHeight as number;
const xClientWidth = document.getElementById('imgPath')?.clientWidth as number;

console.log(xClientHeight);
console.log(xClientWidth);


this.coordinateX =  xClientWidth - event.coordinates[0].yposition;
this.coordinateY = xClientHeight - event.coordinates[0].xposition;



(document.getElementById('rec1') as HTMLInputElement).innerHTML = "<img src='../../../assets/rec.gif'  style='width:25px; height:25px;'></img>";

}


showImage(imagePath: string) {
return this.environment.endpoints.backendBaseUrl + imagePath; // 
imagePath
}
```

My HTML Code

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of jsonData">
                <td (click)="showCorner(row)">{{ row.name }}</td>
               
            </tr>         
        </tbody>
    </table>

<div class="flex-1 relative">
  <div class="relative">
    <img id="imgPath" (click.double)="addBorder($event)"  style="width: 832px; max-width: fit-content;" [src]="showImage(partListImage.imagePath)">
    <div id="rec1" class="absolute" [style]="{'left': coordinateX+ 'px', 'top': coordinateY+ 'px'}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in images there are numbers.
And each number when you click on table will be selected.

Comment: I had to adjust your coordinates quite a bit there. Is [this better](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-vhyajt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)?

Comment: The problem it is that coordinates are coming from backend which I cannot change them and somehow I need to make it like you did because as you see in img there are around 40 coordinates for 1 image and I have around 100 Img I cannot them manually

Comment: Do you have the original dimensions of the image (width and height) for which the backend coordinates are valid?

Comment: @VonC the img dimensions which are coming from backend are 1664 × 2344 for all imgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem it is that coordinates are coming from backend which I cannot change them and somehow I need to make it like you did because as you see in img there are around 40 coordinates for 1 image and I have around 100 Img I cannot them manually
>
> the img dimensions which are coming from backend are 1664 × 2344 for all imgs

As provided by the backend, set the original image dimensions (1664x2344) in your component.
Compute the scaling factors based on the current displayed size of the image in the frontend and the original dimensions. Apply Scaling to Coordinates: Use the scaling factors to adjust the coordinates received from the backend.
I have adjusted them in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-vhyajt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Your `app.component.ts` would be:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('imgPath', { static: false }) imgElementRef!: ElementRef;
  coordinateX!: number;
  coordinateY!: number;
  originalCoordinates: any; // To store original coordinates
  columns = [
    {
      itemNumber: '1',
      partNumber: '4400535240',
      coordinates: [
        {
          itemCounter: 0,
          xposition: 970,
          yposition: 375,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      itemNumber: '2',
      partNumber: '4400541680',
      coordinates: [
        {
          itemCounter: 0,
          xposition: 1282,
          yposition: 522,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      itemNumber: '4',
      partNumber: '4400541390',
      coordinates: [
        {
          itemCounter: 0,
          xposition: 445,
          yposition: 307,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  constructor() {
    // Deep copy of original columns to preserve original coordinates
    this.originalCoordinates = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.columns));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Calculate and apply scaling when the view is initialized
    this.calculateAndApplyScaling();
  }

  showCorner(event: any) {
    // Calculate and apply scaling
    this.calculateAndApplyScaling();

    // Use the scaled coordinates
    this.coordinateX = event.coordinates[0].xposition;
    this.coordinateY = event.coordinates[0].yposition + 80;

    // Log coordinates to console
    console.log('Selected Coordinates:', this.coordinateX, this.coordinateY);

    // Update the border element
    this.updateBorderElement();
  }

  private calculateAndApplyScaling() {
    const imgElement = this.imgElementRef.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement;
    const currentWidth = imgElement.clientWidth;
    const currentHeight = imgElement.clientHeight;

    console.log(
      'Image Current Width:',
      currentWidth,
      'Current Height:',
      currentHeight
    );

    // Use naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties
    const originalWidth = imgElement.naturalWidth;
    const originalHeight = imgElement.naturalHeight;

    const scaleX = currentWidth / this.originalWidth;
    const scaleY = currentHeight / this.originalHeight;

    console.log('Scale Factor X:', scaleX, 'Scale Factor Y:', scaleY);

    // Apply scale factors to each original coordinate
    this.columns.forEach((column, index) => {
      column.coordinates.forEach((coordinate, coordIndex) => {
        const originalCoordinate =
          this.originalCoordinates[index].coordinates[coordIndex];
        coordinate.xposition = originalCoordinate.xposition * scaleX;
        coordinate.yposition = originalCoordinate.yposition * scaleY;

        console.log(
          `Original Coordinates: (${originalCoordinate.xposition}, ${originalCoordinate.yposition}), Scaled Coordinates: (${coordinate.xposition}, ${coordinate.yposition})`
        );
      });
    });
  }

  private updateBorderElement() {
    const recElement = document.getElementById('rec1') as HTMLElement;
    if (recElement) {
      recElement.style.border = '2px solid red';
      recElement.style.width = '25px';
      recElement.style.height = '25px';
      recElement.style.left = this.coordinateX + 'px';
      recElement.style.top = this.coordinateY + 'px';

      console.log(
        'Border Element Updated:',
        `Left: ${this.coordinateX}px, Top: ${this.coordinateY}px`
      );
    }
  }

  addBorder(event: any) {
    console.log('Add Border Event:', event);
    const e = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('Bounding Client Rect:', e);
    const xClientH = event.screenY;
    const xClientY = event.screenX;

    this.coordinateX = xClientY;
    this.coordinateY = xClientH;
    console.log(
      'Coordinates from Event:',
      `X: ${this.coordinateX}, Y: ${this.coordinateY}`
    );

    const recElement = document.getElementById('rec1') as HTMLInputElement;
    if (recElement) {
      recElement.innerHTML =
        "<img src='../../assets/flow-editor/Image/rec.gif' style='width:25px; height:25px;'></img>";
    }
  }
}
```

And your HTML code makes sure the positioning is absolute relative to the parent container of the image.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of columns">
      <td (click)="showCorner(row)">{{ row.itemNumber }}</td>
      <td (click)="showCorner(row)">{{ row.partNumber }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="flex-1 relative">
  <div class="relative">
    <img
      #imgPath
      (click.double)="addBorder($event)"
      style="width: 832px; max-width: fit-content;"
      src="../../assets/flow-editor/Image/ev00129014.png"
    />
    <div
      id="rec1"
      class="absolute"
      [ngStyle]="{ left: coordinateX + 'px', top: coordinateY + 'px' }"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I had to adjust any assets path from `../assets/...` to `../../assets/...` to make sure the assets images  are properly displayed.

Comment: Why not to use `HTMLImageElement:naturalWidth/naturalHeight` properties instead of hardcoded values?

Comment: @yurzui Good point. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @VonC but as you see there are some same numbers but different coordinates. The problem for example we have 2 of 91 which habe different coordinates but it is always one getting selected and not the others.

Comment: @TheCoderGuy Can you clarify the issue? Do you see a problem when using the [fork I have done from your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-vhyajt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)?

Comment: @VonC I will describe it when I reach home at my pc. It has to do if one Object has more then 1 coordinate but I will try to explain on comment later

Comment: @VonC I have updated stackblitz added some other objects.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-r3bsbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @TheCoderGuy OK. Seems to be working. Except for the second 83 `X0-00073000`. What is the issue left to solve?

Comment: @VonC that is the issue for the second it is not working. So if I have 2 same then this is happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256457/discussion-between-vonc-and-thecoderguy).

Comment: @VonC Is there any possibility here, so when we click on image by itself to be selected for example if in image I select number 81 it will add automatically the border and not always from the row ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @TheCoderGuy To enable clicking directly on the image and automatically selecting a specific area (like number 81) with a border, you can implement a feature that calculates which part of the image is being clicked based on the mouse click coordinates relative to the image. That would involve comparing the click coordinates with the known positions of the numbers on the image. That would be a good separate question.

Comment: @VonC here you have it man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143331/following-question-of-https-stackoverflow-com-q-77731276-9560126